# How do I solve this Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) conflict?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, automatic-ref-counting

I have a `UIViewController` that requires the Facebook login button to be present in the screen. Now, Facebook iOS button requires the ARC to be OFF.

On the other hand, in the same `UIViewController` I am using `NSTimer` to show few photos as a slideshow at the background - this feature requires ARC setting.

So, I have a single file that requires ARC for one of the components, while not for other.

The exact problem is in this code:

```
-(void)handleTimer {

    [UIView transitionWithView:imageView duration:3 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut) animations:^{
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[myImages objectAtIndex:imagePtr]];
    } completion:nil];

    if(imagePtr == (myImages.count) - 1)
        imagePtr = 0;
    else
        imagePtr = imagePtr + 1;
}
```

If I disable ARC for the file that has this code, it throws an error at this line:

```
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[myImages objectAtIndex:imagePtr]];
```

The error reads:

```
Thread 1 : EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
```

Actually, I have a time as you see above, to continuously update the image in imageView.

myImageView is of type

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
```

So, what is the problem here?

Here is how myImages are initialized in viewDidLoad() method:

```
@interface ViewController () {
    UIImage *nextImage;
    NSArray *myImages;
    int imagePtr;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize imageView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    myImages = @[@"image1.jpg", @"image2.jpg", @"image3.jpg", @"image4.jpg", @"image5.jpg", @"image6.jpg", @"image7.jpg", @"image8.jpg", @"image9.jpg",
                 @"image10.jpg", @"image11.jpg", @"image12.jpg", @"image13.jpg",
                 @"image14.jpg", @"image15.jpg", @"image16.jpg", @"image17.jpg",
                 @"image18.jpg", @"image19.jpg", ];
    imagePtr = 0;

    NSTimer *timer;

    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[myImages objectAtIndex:imagePtr]];
    imagePtr = imagePtr + 1;

    //imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[myImages objectAtIndex:imagePtr]];

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 3
                                             target: self
                                           selector: @selector(handleTimer)
                                           userInfo: nil
                                            repeats: YES];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Comment: There is nothing about NSTimer which requires ARC. Are you clear on how to enable and disable ARC on a per-file basis?

Comment: Put `-fno-objc-arc` flag, in `Build Phases->Compile Sources` section for the file.

Comment: Both ARC and MRC classes can be used by the same class, even if the class is ARC or MRC.

Comment: Yes, I do know how to enable and disable ARC for a file. Edited my question with the exact problem. Please see and suggest.

Comment: When the exception is thrown, what is deallocated?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "it"?

Comment: What is the exact exception / error displayed. Please add to your question.

Comment: Can you please add the error which compiler throw when you remove ARC?

Comment: Can you try to run the app with adding NSZombieenabled keyword or add zombie in environment settings?.

Comment: I enabled Zombie and now it says: [__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x10924ce60

Comment: Looks like it is deallocated. What happened?

Comment: `myImages` is deallocated. How are you declaring `myImages`?

Comment: It is solved now because I initialized the NSArray again in the timer method. But why do I need to do it, strange. Before, it was initialized in the viewDidLoad() method. Does calling the timer method deallocate the NSArray before?

Comment: How are you initialized the NSArray? Can you put the code of view did load method if possible?

Comment: Edited and put the top level of my file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller is probably compiled under MRC. That means that your ivars doesn't retain values you assign to them, for example:

```
myImages = @[...];
```

Will assign the pointer but the array will get released anyway and when you try to access `myImages` later, the application will crash.

Solutions:

1. MRC - with `retain`
   When assigning to the ivars, retain the value explicitly (`myImages = [@[...] retain];`), don't forget to `release` in your `-dealloc`.
2. MRC - with properties
   Remove your ivars and declare them as properties

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *myImages;
   ```

   ...
   self.myImages = @[...];
   Again, don't forget to release your array in `-dealloc`
3. ARC (the preferred solution) - compile your controller with ARC and the values in ivars will be implicitly `__strong` and retained for you.

Comment: That edit was invalid. If you define the property as `retain`, you don't need to use `retain` explicitly anymore but note you have to use `self.myImages`, not `myImages`.

Comment: Method 2 followed. Perfect!

Comment: Hey that is interesting - I just observed. it. Why does using/not using self.myImages v/s just myImages make a difference, even though it has been declared as (nonatomic, retain)?

Comment: @AbhishekShivkumar That's the basic of Obj-C. `self.property` is invoking a property setter or a getter, it's actually a method call, while `property` is accessing an ivar. That's why I said "remove your ivars". This gets a lot simpler in ARC.